# move_uploaded_file does not work in WordPress (functions.php)

Tags: php, file, contact-form-7

I have a form made with Contact Form 7 and I need to save the attachment in a folder but move_uploaded_file() or copy doesn't work. Do you know how to solve this problem? Thanks!!

```
add_action('wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'save_form' );

function save_form( $wpcf7 ) { 

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["photo1"]["tmp_name"],$_FILES["photo1"]["name"]))
{ /*   CORRECT    */ } 
else {  /*    ERROR   */ } }
```

Hope you can help me, I don't know how continue. In a php file this function works but in Wordpress it's impossible. Thanks very much!!!!

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Thanks for your quickly response!Mail works perfect, I receive the file correctly but this doesn't move any file to the folder, I get an empty folder.

Comment: I have the same problem using Gravity Forms, I think it's a problem when I use this function in an action in "Functions.php" file.

Comment: any idea? I think it's a wordpress protection or something like this...

Comment: Please check folder permission 755 or not.